Not able to add the data in database :postman error:Cannot GET /api/v1/createTodo
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

//load config from env file
require("dotenv").config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

//middleware to parse json request body
app.use(express.json());

//import routes for TODO API
const todoRoutes = require("./routes/todos");

//mount the todo API routes
app.use("/api/v1", todoRoutes);


//start server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started successfully at ${PORT}`);
})

//connect to the database
const dbConnect = require("./config/database");
dbConnect();

//default Route
app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.send(`<h1> This is HOMEPAGE baby</h1>`);
})



**todos.js**`models folder`

const express  = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
//import controller
const {createTodo} = require("../controllers/createTodo");



//define APi routes
router.post("/createTodo", createTodo);


module.exports = router;

**createTodo.js**`controllers folder`
//import th model
const Todo = require("../models/Todo");

//define route handler

exports.createTodo = async(req,res) => {
    try {
            //extract title and description from reauest body
            const {title,description} = req.body;
            //create a new Todo Obj and insert in DB
            const response = await Todo.create({title,description});
            //send a json response with a success flag
            res.status(200).json(
                {
                    success:true,
                    data:response,
                    message:'Entry Created Successfully'
                }
            );
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500)
        .json({
            success:false,
            data:"internal server error",
            message:err.message,
        })
    }
}

**models**`routes folder`

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
            maxLength:50,
        },
        description: {
            type:String,
            required:true,
            maxLength:50,
        },
        createdAt:{
            type:Date,
            required:true,
            default:Date.now(),
        },
        updatedAt:{
            type:Date,
            required:true,
            default:Date.now(),
        }
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Todo", todoSchema);
**
database.js**`config folder`

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

require("dotenv").config();

const dbConnect = () => {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL)
    .then(() => console.log("DB ka Connection is Successful"))
    .catch( (error) => {
        console.log("Issue in DB Connection");
        console.error(error.message);
        process.exit(1);
    } );
}


module.exports = dbConnect;
here db connected but i am unable to add the data
after entering url and data in postman** it shows me the below error
Cannot GET /api/v1/createTodo error typically indicates that the route i am trying to access is not defined
after entering url and data in postman** it shows me the below error
Cannot GET /api/v1/createTodo error typically indicates that the route i am trying to access is not defined
Cannot GET /api/v1/createTodo

It seems, the http method sent from postman is GET. In the router module todos.js, only a POST method has been handled. This could be the possible issue. Please choose POST method in postman before sending data.
